# Exporting AutoCAD symbology/icons into ArcGIS Pro and Field Maps

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, autocad, icon, arcgis-field-maps

EDIT: My boss is the engineer that designs erosion control plans within AutoCAD. How do I obtain the symbology used in his Autocad files to utilize in ArcGIS Pro & Field Maps?
*attaching image of field plans with examples circled in cyan.

[image]

Comment: most likely via an ETL tool - is the AutoCAD text in blocks?

Comment: Unfortunately I know very little of CAD, so I'm not sure. I will reach out to our engineer to find out. I'm editing my post because I'm using "labels" wrong. It's the symbology I need for my field data mapping. Attaching an example from the plans in the original.